# What is the parameter type passed to a Lambda function by a CloudWatch Events - Schedule trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286534/aws-lambda-cloudwatch-event-type) but no answer was provided. What is the parameter type passed to a Lambda function (in Java) by a CloudWatch scheduled event?

In [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html) it says the input type would be one of "Predefined AWS event types defined in the aws-lambda-java-events library.". But this library, as I see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events), doesn't define a scheduled or cloudwatch event type.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you just use `Object` for the input type, schedule an event, and then print the class name?

Comment: Great, that worked! Probably should have thought if that... It turns out the parameter is a LinkedHashMap with the keys and values according to what's defined at the very bottom of [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html) page.

Comment: Then please add this as your answer :)

Comment: I'd love to, but how?

Comment: Comments can't be marked as answers. I'll add an answer and quote your comment there. But other than that, all I can do is upvote your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Following Mark B.'s comment, it turns out the parameter is a LinkedHashMap with the keys and values according to what's defined at the very bottom of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something compatible with JSON so that it works with any language supported by AWS Lambda. I'm guessing it's the same as event object, therefore try `Map<String, Object>`