# AWS Lambda function + Cloudwatch, how to pass the right parameters to a timed execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have had success building functions on AWS Lambda and passing parameters to the function to test and execute as I see fit. However, I am finding it hard to locate where to configure what needs to be passed to my functions on a timed event using Cloudwatch. I see the easiest way was to have no event or context (event=None and context=None) but as I have become more sophisticated I have some testing parameters now built in that require me to simply pass the following:

```
{
   "testing" : "True"
}
```

Again, I already have the function up and running but now it is built to accept this when it is needing to actually perform it's job for the management team:

```
{
   "testing" : "False"
}
```

I do see configs for Event Bus being set to default but I cannot locate what CloudWatch was actually doing in the first place so I can modify it (hopefully) to pass the False statement to my function.

All my functions are in python 3.7 and if more info is needed, let me know. I have reviewed questions on here regarding similar issues, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288225/what-is-the-parameter-type-passed-to-a-lambda-function-by-a-cloudwatch-events) but cannot locate these libraries and I believe I would need to configure something custom in the future as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar to what you're after - I trigger a Lambda to create a snapshot of an EBS volume.  I have used the console to configure my Cloudwatch events.  In Events->Rules->Actions (upper right hand corner)->Edit, I have the following:

[image]

My constant JSON looks like:

```
{
"volumeId": "vol-0c4079999999999",
 "description":"Jenkins Snapshot",
 "name": "jenkins-snapshot"
}
```

And I parse this information out to use in my Lambda.  I have multiple events that use this same Lambda and they each just have a different constant JSON in them.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you, I will give this a shot and edit this comment with my result.

Comment: Cannot edit the above but this was correct and worked like a charm at the scheduled execution. Thank you!